# What is this particular sed command doing?

Tags: sed

```
sed -n -E -e '/word/,$ p' filename.txt
```

More specific Questions:

Why is `-e` needed here? Does it serve any purpose in the example?

I know `p` is for print and `$` indicates the end of the line **but what does the compination `,$ p` do exactly here?**

Comment: In the context of an *address range*, `$` means the last line of the file rather than the end of a line: see [Addresses overview](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Addresses-overview)

Comment: I might recommend to have at hand any of the cheatsheets that can be found in the web. This URL searches for [PDF's of them on Duckduckgo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sed+cheatsheet+filetype%3Apdf&ia=web)

Answer (score 3):

`/word/,$` is the address range for the `p` command.

`/word/,$p` will apply the `p` command (print) to all lines from the first that contains `word` anywhere on it, to the end of the file.

`-e` is not needed in this example as there is only one expression for `sed` to execute.  You also do not need `-E` as the example is not making use of POSIX extended regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

- `-e` tell sed to use next arg as command
- `/word/,$` select all line from the one having word to end of file.
- `p` print

if you forget `-n` you will have whole file printed